# Mouse Jumping to bottom left on left key press

Tags: mouse

I have noticed on laptops with a touch pad with embedded buttons that frequency when you are scrolling and press the left button the mouse pointer moves to the bottom left of the screen.

This seems to happen when you are using two fingers on the pad, one for positioning of the pointer and the other for pressing the left button.

I have seen this on several HP Laptops with nVidia Graphics cards.

However, this seems to be dependent on a fresh install of Ubuntu versions, see below:

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS -> Shows the problem
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS -> Works fine
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS -> Shows the problem

I currently have a working laptop from an install of 14.04.3 LTS but it is constantly asking to update drivers for hardware (enablement message). But if I do this update, then the mouse problem returns and I also get a problem with the nVidia Driver.

Has anyone else noticed this ? There must be something with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS that makes it work ?

Thanks